# Algebra, doubts regarding terms in binomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, binomial-theorem

I've been told, a binomial is an expression having only 2 terms.

So, is $(x+y)^2 $ also a binomial? Shouldn't it be a trinomial as it would expand into $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $?
Then, if $(x+y)^2 $ is a trinomial. 
Why did they name it's expansion method, "Binomial Theorem"? Why not call it "Polynomial Theorem"?

Comment: Raising a binomial to a nonnegative integer power

Comment: x+ y is a binomial.  The "binomial" in "binomial theorem" is referring to that.

Comment: A binomial is indeed an expression that consists of two terms. If two expressions are algebraically equivalent, the number of terms doesn't necessarily have to be the same. For example $x +x = 2x$ can be interpreted as a binomial or a monomial. This is of course only a matter of definition ...

Comment: please mark as solved if you are not expecting any further explanations

Comment: @emma just to be sure, from what I understand $(x+y)^2 $ is a binomial, right? (So it doesn't matter whether or not they are raised to any power?) while it's expansion, $ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $ is trinomial? Am I correct?

Comment: A _binomial_ is a sum of two monomials, so e.g. $x+y$. A _trinomial_ is the sum of three monomials, so $x+y+z.$ A _multinomial_ is the sum of $n$ monomials $x_1+x_2+...+x_n.$ The binomial/multinomial theorem describe the algebraic expansion of these when taken to some power $k$. So, no: $(x+y)^2$ is not a binomial, it's a binomial taken to the power of 2. And $x^2+2xy+y^2$ is not a trinomial, because the summands are not monomials.

Answer (score 1):

A *binomial* is the sum of two monomials $a$ and $b,$ i.e. $a+b$. The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) describes the algebraic expansion of powers of a binomial, i.e. $(a+b)^k.$ A generalization of this is the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) that describes the expansion of the sum of $m$ [monomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial), i.e. $(a_1+a_2+...+a_m)^k.$ So, the name refers to the number of summands that are taken some power $k$.